# Can a multitenant google app engine (java) application authenticate with google apps users?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

So now Google released the multi-tenant feature for gae.

Assuming i am going to implement a google app engine application and put it on google apps market place.

suppose www.doma.com and www.domb.com bought the application.
can usera from doma and userb from domb authenticate to this application with their google apps domain username (in other words) can usera@doma and userb@domb use authenticate with gae?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Google does not limit users when they go through OpenID or Google Accounts authentication procedure, your code should do this. After user is authenticated control is handed back to your code - at this point you should check users data and decide to pass the request through or not.

Also, if you want to use `doma.com` and `domb.com` as your domain names on GAE you need to own this domains and create separate Google Apps account for each of them. This means that random user cannot have `user@doma.com` email address (unless you manually created an account for them on Google Apps).